# Как реализовать пользовательский блок "Обо мне"?

Tags: wordpress

На сайте-визитке есть блок "Обо мне", состоящий из изображения и описания владельца сайта. В админ-панеле WP необходимо добавить отдельную вкладку "Обо мне", где владелец мог бы загрузить какую он пожелает свою фотографию и написать о себе необходимую информацию. Как реализовать данную задачу?

P.S. я делал свой тип записи (register_post_type()) "Обо мне", добавлял к этому типу custom fields на изображение и текст и выводил через ключи содержимое пользовательских полей в блоке сайта "Обо мне" в цикле the_loop постов, относящихся к типу "Обо мне" (да, там была всего одна запись).

Да, все очень запутано, костыльно и вообще неправильно, я новичок в WP. Не ругайте сильно)

Comment: Лучше добавлять инфу на страницу профиля пользователя,через user_meta https://wp-kama.ru/question/dannye-polzovatelya

Comment: @KAGGDesign, я извиняюсь, но что вы понимаете под "страница профиля пользователя"? Поймите меня правильно, это вопрос из тематики "переменные" в WP. Я не знаю есть ли такой механизм, но блок "Обо мне" это один из вариантов задач. Т.е. представьте себе, что в шапке сайта есть "Цитата дня" и пользователю бы хотелось иметь возможность заходить в админку WP (каждый день), видеть там вкладку "Цитата Дня", кликать на неё, после чего ему было бы доступно текстовое поле, он туда пишет ТУ самую цитату, сохраняет изменения и на сайте она благополучно отображается

Comment: @KAGGDesign по-моему тут речь не о заполнении профиля пользователя, а о сайте-визитке и странице "Обо мне", которая что-то вроде "About Us". А владелец сайта - не один из многих пользователей, а единственный человек, которому посвящён этот сайт. Тут, имхо, всё решается созданием страницы и при необходимости - отдельного шаблона под неё типа `page-$id.php`

Comment: Я бы сделал этот блок с помощью кастомайзера и не парился. Посмотрите wp_customize

Comment: @ivankalita_, профиль пользователя это твой_сайт/wp-admin/profile.php Там всё заполняется. Единственное что - это можно добавить плагин для загрузки локального аватара, тк по умолчанию аватар берётся с https://gravatar.com/